# How to get rid of the > sign?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word

[W10; Lenovo laptop; Outlook 2010; Word 2010; Google Chrome; Gmail]

How do I get rid of this sign `>`, which appear at the beginning of each line in my long list in my W10, Word 2010?

Many internet answers suggested to:

- highlight the list
- go to home
- clear formatting

I did all of that and the only thing I got was double space on my list, but still with the annoying `>` signs.

From those internet answers, I gathered that `>` is NOT part of the formatting, so this makes my problem more complicated.

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. You can add a screenshot by uploading it to imgur.com and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1373175/edit) your question and add the link there or use the image button while editing your question (is the same, but takes less steps). Someone with enough reputation will make the image visible afterwards.

Comment: Clear Formatting removes things such as bold, italics, or special fonts or colors. It does not remove actual characters from the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Find and Replace** sounds like the correct tool for this job.

I'm assuming you've copied a list from your web browser into a Word document, and it came with these unwanted characters.

The easiest way to remove them is to highlight and copy one of the offending characters, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Find and Replac**e dialog. Paste the offending character into the **Find what:** box, and leave the **Replace with:** box blank. Then click **Replace** (or **Replace all**, but only if you know you want to remove EVERY instance of that character throughout the entire list).

Comment: Worked like magic!

Answer (score 0):

I can not be certain without an image but this sounds like Word is creating a bulleted list out of your lines.

The following is a link from Microsoft that shows you how to create a bulleted list. Creating and removing it follows the same steps.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-bulleted-or-numbered-list-9ff81241-58a8-4d88-8d8c-acab3006a23e

In essence: select your list, go to Home but instead of clearing the formatting, click the icon that has three dots with lines next to each dot. The icon next to it would most likely be the same but with numbers instead of dots.